Umbraco 13 forms conditions rendering script
I am using a custom theme for umbraco forms and to make conditions work for the custom theme I had to add the following to my Script.cshtml file:
Html.AddFormThemeScriptFile("~/App_Plugins/UmbracoForms/Assets/themes/default/umbracoforms.js");

But this script file umbraco.js is not loaded directly when the form is loaded on a new browser page and conditions do not work unless the site is refreshed once then the script can be seen and conditions work as expected.
What could this depend on ?

Maybe script being added after the page has already been loaded, which results in the conditions not working until a refresh. Ensure that the script is included in the page before the form is rendered, or use $(document).ready() or window.onload

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
